# Jqgrid popup positioning trouble

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing the problem of positioning of the update confirmation box/ delete confirmation box/ No row selected error box/ edit modal popup/ add modal popup etc to the center of the screen ….. I have looked a lot but could not find any helpful answers ….. can you please suggest that what can be done to achieve this result. I have two grids and the default positioning is not going well with it as for the second grid the popup's appear underneath and I have scroll down to get to the edit/add modal popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the most effective way to change position of **all** message boxes and dialogs displayed by jqGrid would be subclassing of `$.jgrid.showModal` method internally used in jqGrid. I hope that you'll can create the corresponding solution based on idea from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786177/315935). Instead of animation effects you can change position of the dialog/message box before is will be shown.