# How to access the cancel button event in jQGrid Edit dialog box

Tags: jqgrid, event-handling

Is there an event associated with the cancel button of various jQGrid dialog boxes like ADD, Edit and Delete ? For my edit dialog box, I need to do some processing when the user clicks the cancel button.

please help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it could be enough to use `onClose` callback for form editing (see the documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2)).

If you would fund out that the callback are called not allays (I don't tested it in the current version of jqGrid) then you can choose another way. If you really need to process all closing of all dialogs you can consider to overwrite or to subclass `$.jgrid.closeModal` or `$.jgrid.hideModal` functions. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DialogAnimation.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786177/315935) (compare the code with original one [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.common.js#L15-L21)).