# dont count comma separated in maxlength jqgrid column deciamal

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have input field which contains decimal and special characters e.g. comma 
and dot while calulating the maxLength of the field i want to skip special characters :

```
{ 
  name: "amount", 
  width: 62, 
  template: "number",
  formatter: "number", 
  formatoptions: {
    decimalSeparator:",", 
    thousandsSeparator: " ", 
    decimalPlaces: 4, 
    defaultValue: '0.0000'
  },
  editoptions: {
    maxlength; 5
    type: "number"
  }
},
```

I when edit inline record filed "PackageCode" is count decimalSeparator I want don't count decimalSeparator
see demo :https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/288/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what you need to implement. jqGrid don't count `decimalSeparator` or anything else during inline editing. It just set static value of `maxlength`, which you use (`maxlength="5"`). If you need to allows to edit more long values, like `125.22` in your demo, then you can set `maxlength` dynamically like in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/309/, which used

```
editoptions: {
    maxlength: 5,
    dataInit: function (elem, options) {
        var currentLength = String(elem.value).length;
        if (currentLength > 5) {
            elem.setAttribute("maxlength", currentLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you should fix `defaultValue` to use comma instead of dot (`0,00` instead of `0.00` or `0,0000` instead of `0.0000`) if you use formatter option `decimalSeparator:","`.